# Reference for the degenerate orthogonal Procrustes problem

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, optimization, matrix-calculus, orthogonal-matrices

$\newcommand{\SOn}{\operatorname{SO}_n}$
$\newcommand{\On}{\operatorname{O}_n}$
$\newcommand{\Sym}{\operatorname{Sym}_n}$
$\newcommand{\Skew}{\operatorname{Skew}_n}$
$\newcommand{\dist}{\operatorname{dist}}$
$\newcommand{\Sig}{\Sigma}$
$\newcommand{\sig}{\sigma}$
$\newcommand{\al}{\alpha}$
$\newcommand{\id}{\operatorname{Id}}$

This question is a reference request. Consider the following claim.

> Let $A $ be a $n \times n$ real matrix.
>
> Then an orthogonal matrix $Q$ is a closest matrix to $A$ in $ O(n)$ (w.r.t the Euclidean Frobenius norm) if and only if it is an orthogonal polar factor of $A$, i.e. if $A=QP$, where $P=\sqrt{A^TA}$.

**Question:** Where can I find a reference for this claim? (I am quite sure this is well-known)

> I ask for a reference for the coincidence of the set of orthogonal minimizers with the set of all possible factors in the polar decomposition.

**Note that if $A$ is invertible, then there is a unique polar factor, which is also the unique minimizer. I specifically look for references which deal with the general (possibly singular) case.**

(BTW, the more interesting direction is why every minimizer is a polar factor).

I tried to look e.g. in [this book](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/procrustes-problems-9780198510581?cc=il&lang=en&), but found no mention of this.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/procrustes-problem

Comment: Horn and Johnson's *Matrix Analysis* 2nd ed Section 7.4.5 has the condition the a unitary matrix $U$ minimizes $\|A-U\|$ if and only if $AU^*$ is positive semidefinite. Not exactly what you're asking for but it does deal with the general case.